# Extract url from a long string and append it to another string to make a new url

Tags: javascript, string, url, substring

I am new to JS, I have a long string from which I need to extract the substring **`src=/sites/default/files/text_images/cover/gita.jpg`** (inside the `img` tag as seen in the string). 
Then I need to construct a new url: **http://12.23.34/sites/default/files/text_images/cover/gita.jpg**. 
Please let me know how can I do it.

The following is the long string.

```
"\n\n<!-- THEME DEBUG -->\n<!-- THEME HOOK: 'image_formatter' -->\n<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/field/image-formatter.html.twig' -->\n  \n\n<!-- THEME DEBUG -->\n<!-- THEME HOOK: 'image' -->\n<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/field/image.html.twig' -->\n<img src=\"/sites/default/files/text_images/cover/gita.jpg\" alt=\"Bhagavad Gita\" typeof=\"foaf:Image\" />\n\n<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/field/image.html.twig' -->\n\n\n\n<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/field/image-formatter.html.twig' -->\n\n",
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```js
const str = `"\n\n<!-- THEME DEBUG -->\n<!-- THEME HOOK: 'image_formatter' -->\n<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/field/image-formatter.html.twig' -->\n  \n\n<!-- THEME DEBUG -->\n<!-- THEME HOOK: 'image' -->\n<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/field/image.html.twig' -->\n
<img src=\"/sites/default/files/text_images/cover/gita.jpg\" alt=\"Bhagavad Gita\" typeof=\"foaf:Image\" />\n\n<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/field/image.html.twig' -->\n\n\n\n<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/field/image-formatter.html.twig' -->\n\n",`
const div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML=str;
let url = new URL(div.querySelector("img").src);
url.hostname = "12.23.34";
url.protocol="http:";
console.log(url.href);
```

Alternative for older browsers or if you need the anchor

```js
const str = `"\n\n<!-- THEME DEBUG -->\n<!-- THEME HOOK: 'image_formatter' -->\n<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/field/image-formatter.html.twig' -->\n  \n\n<!-- THEME DEBUG -->\n<!-- THEME HOOK: 'image' -->\n<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/field/image.html.twig' -->\n
<img src=\"/sites/default/files/text_images/cover/gita.jpg\" alt=\"Bhagavad Gita\" typeof=\"foaf:Image\" />\n\n<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/field/image.html.twig' -->\n\n\n\n<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/field/image-formatter.html.twig' -->\n\n",`
const div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML=str;
const a = document.createElement("a")
const img = div.querySelector("img");
a.href=img.src;
a.hostname = "12.23.34";
a.protocol="http:";
a.textContent = img.alt;
div.innerHTML="";
div.appendChild(a)
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Removing the port:

```js
const str = `"\n\n<!-- THEME DEBUG -->\n<!-- THEME HOOK: 'image_formatter' -->\n<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/field/image-formatter.html.twig' -->\n  \n\n<!-- THEME DEBUG -->\n<!-- THEME HOOK: 'image' -->\n<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/field/image.html.twig' -->\n
<img src=\"http://localhost:12345/sites/default/files/text_images/cover/gita.jpg\" alt=\"Bhagavad Gita\" typeof=\"foaf:Image\" />\n\n<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/field/image.html.twig' -->\n\n\n\n<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/field/image-formatter.html.twig' -->\n\n",`
const div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML=str;
const a = document.createElement("a")
const img = div.querySelector("img");
a.href=img.src;
a.hostname = "12.23.34";
a.protocol="http:";
a.port="";
a.textContent = img.alt;
div.innerHTML="";
div.appendChild(a)
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

If you MUST use regex (NOT recommended), try this

```js
const re = /<img src=\"(.*?)\"/;
const src = `"\n\n<!-- THEME DEBUG -->\n<!-- THEME HOOK: 'image_formatter' -->\n<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/field/image-formatter.html.twig' -->\n  \n\n<!-- THEME DEBUG -->\n<!-- THEME HOOK: 'image' -->\n<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/field/image.html.twig' -->\n<img src=\"/sites/default/files/text_images/cover/gita.jpg\" alt=\"Bhagavad Gita\" typeof=\"foaf:Image\" />\n\n<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/field/image.html.twig' -->\n\n\n\n<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/field/image-formatter.html.twig' -->\n\n"`.match(re)[1]
console.log("http://12.23.34"+src)
```

Comment: I am using the first method you had mentioned. But I am getting the url like so: http://12.34.6.78:8100/sites/default/files/text_images/cover/gita.jpg. I dont know why 8100 is coming.

Comment: I did not put it there.

Comment: I am getting the url as href: "http://localhost:8100/sites/default/files/text_images/cover/gita.jpg. After I assign url.hostname="12.23.34", it becomes href: "http://l12.23.34:8100/sites/default/files/text_images/cover/gita.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Bad coding with good result

```js
let urlRaw = `\n\n<!-- THEME DEBUG -->\n<!-- THEME HOOK: 'image_formatter' -->\n<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/field/image-formatter.html.twig' -->\n  \n\n<!-- THEME DEBUG -->\n<!-- THEME HOOK: 'image' -->\n<!-- BEGIN OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/field/image.html.twig' -->\n<img **src=\"/sites/default/files/text_images/cover/gita.jpg\**" alt=\"Bhagavad Gita\" typeof=\"foaf:Image\" />\n\n<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/field/image.html.twig' -->\n\n\n\n<!-- END OUTPUT from 'core/themes/stable/templates/field/image-formatter.html.twig' -->\n\n`;

console.log(`http://12.23.0.34`+ urlRaw.split("**")[1].replace(`src="`,""));
```

Comment: Also you modified the string before extracting. How was that supposed to happen? At least split on `<img src=\"`

Comment: @mplungjan
Yup, you are right, this is just an idea to extract data from the string.
conditions and logics change according to the requirement. I have read your answer that was awesome!
indeed